# How to grouped values in object?

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function that allows you to group values in an object, but it doesn't work quite right

This is my varation

```
const response = Object.values(
      footerMenu.reduce((acc, key) => {
        const { databaseId, parentDatabaseId } = key;
        acc[parentDatabaseId] = (acc[parentDatabaseId] || []).concat(key);
        return acc;
      }, {})
    );
```

example data:

```
[{parentDatabase: 0, databaseId: 5728}, {parentDatabseId: 5728, databaseId: 5762}....{parentDatabse: 0, databaseId: 4532}, {parentDatabaseId: 4532, databaseId: 3221} ...]
```

how to group an item so that parent Database Id == 0 has its own items that relate to it

Comment: Why do you use `Object.values`? Just remove that call.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: The array you said you're working with has syntax problems i rectified that for you in the answer below

Answer (score 1):

you have to perform a simple manipulation with the array — group the items by parentDatabaseId

The usual way is by invoking the array.reduce() method with the right callback function:

```js
let array=[{parentDatabase: 0, databaseId: 5728}, {parentDatabase: 5728, databaseId: 5762},{parentDatabase: 0, databaseId: 4532}, {parentDatabase: 4532, databaseId: 3221} ]

const groupByDbId = array.reduce((group, item) => {
  const { parentDatabase } = item;
  group[parentDatabase] = group[parentDatabase] ?? [];
  group[parentDatabase].push(item);
  return group;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(groupByDbId, null, 2));
```

Comment: khm, it's grouped all parentDatabase, need { parentDatabase: 0, databaseId: 5728 },
    { parentDatabase: 5728, databaseId: 5762 },
    { parentDatabase: 5728, databaseId: 5763 },
    { parentDatabase: 0, databaseId: 4532 },
    { parentDatabase: 4532, databaseId: 3221 },
    { parentDatabase: 4532, databaseId: 3222 }, =>
    {
      "first": {
      { parentDatabase: 5728, databaseId: 5762 },
      { parentDatabase: 5728, databaseId: 5763 },
      },
      "second": {
      { parentDatabase: 4532, databaseId: 3221 },
      { parentDatabase: 4532, databaseId: 3222 },
    }